# IntelliJ : types of entities to be added to the project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I created new maven project in IntelliJ Idea (13.1.5) ( using quickstart archetype). It was created project structure with folders src/main/java/.. , src/test/java/.. . When trying to add new file to project , I don't get options for adding java related entities ( java class, package , etc) 
When I created Java project - I can add new java class, package etc...
The question is - where should I configure entity types to be added for specific type of project (maven in my case ) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In intellij , Right click on `java` directory located  `YourProject->src->main->java` then you will see the option to add new java file

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I also expected to see such option( as for java project) . But currently I don't see such option when I right-click on folder you mentioned.

Comment: Did you see the `java` folder in blue color? if not can you right click on `java` and choose `MarkDirectoryAs->Source Root` and then try

Comment: Glad it helps, you can always upvote if you find the answer useful and mark it as answer if it answer your question :)